# java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user xxx nor current process has android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE

Tags: java, android

Использую `android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE` в приложении для очистки кэша. На андроид 6+ получаю ошибку:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user xxx nor current process has android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE.

Код:

```
try {
    Class[] classes = new Class[]{Long.TYPE, IPackageDataObserver.class};
    Long maxLong = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    Method method = pm.getClass().getMethod("freeStorageAndNotify", classes);
    method.invoke(pm, maxLong, new CachePackageDataObserver());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Знаю, что `CLEAR_APP_CACHE` имеет protectionLevel: system или signature. system не подходит (нужны рут права). Как правильно подписать приложение (signature)? Знаю, что для такой подписи нужны 3 файла: signapk.jar, platform.x509.pem, platform.pk8. Вопрос: где мне их взять? Или как сделать чтобы не было такой ошибки?